# Android studio gradle sync error with firebase : Response 204: No Content has no content

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, gradle

Since this morning i have trouble to sync my android project in android-studio.

When i try to do so, i get every time the same errors :
[A part of the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD3S0.png)

All those errors are caused by the same problem :

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Response 204: No Content has no content!
```

And indeed, when trying to access manually to the address there is nothing
[Example of one of them](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-measurement-connector-impl/17.0.3/firebase-measurement-connector-impl-17.0.3-javadoc.jar)

Any idea if it is on my side or on google's/maven's ?

project build.gradle :

```
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0"
    }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module build.gradle :

```
    apply plugin: "com.android.application"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tmproject.nviseur.ticketless_compagnon"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ["*.jar"], dir: "libs")
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:18.0.1"
    implementation "com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5"
}
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem from this morning. It was working yesterday.

I noticed that this problem is somehow only in android studio.
When I build an app with command line, everything is ok.

Command:  `./gradlew clean assembleDebug` (mac os)

Comment: After trying some more, it appear that i can build and execute the app, but it still cause the project window to not change to "dev" mode. I'll continue like that and if the problem disappear in the next few day I'll accept your answer as it let me know that it is not a problem on my side.