# "Could not get resource" Android Studio Gradle Sync Error

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use Google Firebase's ML-Kit for a project with Android Studio 3.2.1. However, when I "Sync the Project with Gradle Files", i can [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkyI8.png) that gradle is failing to get some of the dependencies, although this isn't preventing Gradle from syncing "succesfully". All of these dependencies are related to google-services or firebase.
These are my build.gradle (app module) dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:18.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common:16.1.6'


testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this is my top-level gradle:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'



    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I already checked the [SDK Tools settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMXKg.png).
Do you have any ideas what else could be causing this error?
Thank you in advance!

EDIT: like discribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53408816/android-studio-gradle-sync-error-with-firebase-response-204-no-content-has-no), i tried to build the app with the commandline (gradlew assembleDebug), i don't see any errors. This may work, we'll see.

Comment: Try to move apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' at the top of file

Comment: Thank you for your help! Sadly, it didn't work :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53246632/org-gradle-api-resources-resourceexception-could-not-get-resource-in-android-st this looks same but hasn't answer

Comment: Jeah i've seen this post, but it was closed for no reason ://

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

to this

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me!
This didn't solve the problem though

Comment: did you migrate the project to android-x?

Comment: No, should I? I have never heard of android-x before

Comment: "Refactor > Migrate Android X" and check the "Backup project as Zip file" just in case. Maybe it will work. I'm not sure.

Comment: Mh, makes no difference, I'm afraid. But thank you anyway for helping me:)
offtopic: Is AndroidX actually better? It looks like it isn't causing any problems so far, what is it doing exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it looks like these errors are no problem if you build the app with gradlew clean assembleDebug per commandline. Atleast facedetection works fine now.